# How can I draw a horizontal line spanning only some of the table cells?

Tags: tables, rules

In a table, how can I draw a horizontal line that goes only through some of the cells? I mean a line like the one in the `Foo` and in the `Bar` area of this table:

```
+----+-----+
|Foo |1 |2 |
|    |1 |2 |
|    +--+--+
|    |1 |2 |
|    |1 |2 |
+----+-----+
|Bar |1 |2 |
|    |1 |2 |
|    +--+--+
|    |1 |2 |
|    |1 |2 |
+----+--+--+
```

Comment: If  you need a nested table, visit: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7958/how-to-nest-tables/7964#7964

Answer (score 284, accepted):

Instead of nested tables as xport_is_sleeping suggested, you can also use `\cline{2-3}` which draws a partial line starting on column 2 and ending on column 3 and use `\multirow` to center the words `Foo` and `Bar` on the lines if that's what you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|cc|}\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Foo} & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\\cline{2-3}
    & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Bar} & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\\cline{2-3}
    & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

When making tables, you should also always use the [array](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) package which offers various additional features and improvements (most notably at the vertical and horizontal lines joins).

Comment: `\multirow` cannot accept graphics.

Comment: @xport: Why do you say that? I have no problems when replacing `Foo` by `\includegraphics[height=4em]{image}` inside the `\multirow` in the code above.

Comment: are you sure the image will be vertically centered? :-)

Comment: @xport: with a `\raisebox{-\tabcolsep}{\includegraphics[height=4em]{image}}`, it will be vertically centered, yes.

Comment: I see that \cmidrule{2-3} is another option which puts a bit more pleasing space between the lines.

Answer (score 58):

Here's a solution using `booktabs` and getting rid of of the vertical rules, which leads to a prettier result imho. Have a look at the introduction of the [`booktabs` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/booktabs), which offers some insights in basic table design.

The benefits of `booktabs` are: Much better table spacing, and `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule`, where `\midrule` is thinner than the other two, which looks nice.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
Foo & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\\cmidrule{2-3}% That's the rule you're looking for.
    & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\
\midrule
Bar & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\\cmidrule{2-3}% This too. The numbers designate the columns covered.
    & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{1 and 2 in relation to Foo and Bar.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: doesn't work with longtable, i guess.

Comment: @VineetMenon A quick check makes me think it does work. Also, the `booktabs` documentation explicitly mentions compatibility with `longtable` and provides some hints in section 5. Have a look at that, and if you still can’t work something out, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: oh. my bad, there was a glitch in my source. It's working now. thanks

Comment: Can we do that for non consecutive entries? I mean instead of `\cmidrule{2-3}`, to have `\cmidrule{2, 4 and 5}` in a bigger table? ANSWER: `\cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{4-5}`

Answer (score 26):

Nested table can solve this beautifully.

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|@{}c@{}|}\hline
Foo
&
\begin{tabular}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 \\\hline
1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 \\
\end{tabular}
\tabularnewline\hline
Bar
&
\begin{tabular}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 \\\hline
1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 \\
\end{tabular}
\tabularnewline\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may also try [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package. With `tblr` environment you can use `\cline` command to draw a colorful partial horizontal line. Furthermore, hlines can not cross multirow cells in any case, so you can simply write `\hline` instead of `\cline` in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

Using \verb!\cline!:
\begin{tblr}{|c|cc|}
\hline
\SetCell[r=4]{c} Foo & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\
\cline[blue3]{2-3}
    & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
\SetCell[r=4]{c} Bar & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\
\cline[purple3]{2-3}
    & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\bigskip

Using \verb!\hline!: 
\begin{tblr}{|c|cc|}
\hline
\SetCell[r=4]{c} Foo & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\
\hline[blue3]
    & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
\SetCell[r=4]{c} Bar & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\
\hline[purple3]
    & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Will rowcolor{} also not cross \multirow cells ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that tabular easily with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|cc|}
\Hline
\Block{4-1}{Foo} & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\
\Hline
    & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\
\Hline
\Block{4-1}{Bar} & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\
\Hline
    & 1 & 2 \\
    & 1 & 2 \\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

I want to add just for completion:

If you want several partial lines within one row (and possibly one for only one column), then `\cline{1-1}\cline{3-5}` would be the correct solution. `\cline{1}\cline{3-5}` does **not** work.