# Combine and reduce rows in a table

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I have my template here

```
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{center}
\makebox[\textwidth][c] %[l]
{
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\hline
Topic 1 & Topic 2 & Topic 2  \\
\hline
33333 & 44444 & 55555\\
\hline
aaaaa & bbbbb & 55555\\
\hline
 \end{tabular}
 }
  \hspace*{0mm}
\end{center}
\caption{}
  \label{table:example-app}
\end{table} 


\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I make:

a. the "Topic 2" in the 1st row (2nd and 3rd columns) combined to be a single block, and has the vertical line in between removed?

b. As well as combine "55555" occur in the 2nd and 3rd row (of 3rd column) to be a single block, and has the horizontal line in between removed?

c. In the desired new Table, I hope that "Topic 2" and "55555" only occur once in the new form. Namely, repeated items are combined.

I tried to use the [multirow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8549/how-can-i-draw-a-horizontal-line-spanning-only-some-of-the-table-cells) but I failed (cannot compile in TexShop). Maybe there is a neat way to do that.

Comment: Your questions are all covered here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

Comment: Thanks very much, but I haven't found the one exactly match mine hoped version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is. You shouldn't use the `center` environment for tables or figures, as it adds spurious vertical spacing. Use `\centering` instead. As I didn't see what the `\makebox` command was for, I took the liberty to remove it. Finally, I added some vertical padding to the rows, setting `\arraystretch` to `1.2`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\hline
Topic 1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Topic 2}\\
\hline
33333 & 44444 & \multirow{2}{*}{55555}\\
\cline{1-2}
aaaaa & bbbbb
\\
\hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{}
  \label{table:example-app}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! by the way, if you have tables without caption text, you should change the caption style so that there's no colon for such captions (this can be done with the `caption`package).

Comment: Can you explain what does the alternative of "\cline"? Like is there a "\lline" or "\rline"? the C, L, R version for it? What is the meaning?

Comment: Can you explain what is the meaning: \multirow{2}{*}{} ?

Comment: My remaining puzzle: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367726