# Horizontal line writing over text in multicolumn

Tags: multicolumn, multirow, overleaf

So, I'm trying to write a Table with some information and for the first time in my life im using multirow and multicolumn. Everything was going kind of ok until I decided to use `\hline` and, as you can see in the code, one of the horizontal lines is going through a multicolumn and writing over my text.

> Can someone tell me how I can prevent this from happening?

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Item}}                             & \textbf{CPU33} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Dimensiones}                      & A     \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Consumo}                          & B     \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Ambiente de operación} & Temperatura & C     \\ \hline
                                       & Ruido       & D     \\ \hline
                                       & Vibración   & E     \\ \hline
                                       & Schock      & F     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: My current table]

Comment: You can use `\cline{2-3}` instead of `\hline`.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Don't worry for the formatting :-)....welcome again.

Comment: Thank you so much @Sebastiano for editing the posst and helping!

Comment: @leandriis thank you for your help!

Comment: @AndreaBustos You're welcome and I'm glad to help you...thus you will know clicking on edit how to use the commands to create the key words and the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the \cline command to draw horizontal line in only two cells. As the code is shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Item}}                             & \textbf{CPU33} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Dimensiones}                      & A     \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Consumo}                          & B     \\ \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{Ambiente de operación} & Temperatura & C  \\ \cline{2-3}
        & Ruido       & D     \\\cline{2-3}
        & Vibración   & E     \\ \cline{2-3}
        & Schock      & F     \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The table is
[image: table]

You can also refer to the following link [How can I draw a horizontal line spanning only some of the table cells?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8549/how-can-i-draw-a-horizontal-line-spanning-only-some-of-the-table-cells)

Comment: Thank you so much! And for the link, I will be checking that out

Answer (score 1):

In order to make sure a horizontal line does not cross a `\multirow` cell, you can use `\cline` instead of `\hline`. Specify which columns your line should appear in.

Additionally, I have added the `cellspace` package in order to allow for a small vertical white space above and below of the text in each cell. In the third example, I also included a table using no vertical lines, no `\multirow` and just a fex horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{booktabs} % only used in third example

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|0c|0c|0c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|0c|}{\textbf{Item}}                    & \textbf{CPU33} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|0c|}{Dimensiones}                      & A              \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|0c|}{Consumo}                          & B              \\ \hline
        \multirow{4.25}{*}{Ambiente de operación} & Temperatura & C              \\ \cline{2-3}
                                               & Ruido          & D              \\ \cline{2-3}
                                               & Vibración      & E              \\ \cline{2-3}
                                               & Schock         & F              \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|0c|0c|0c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|0c|}{\textbf{Item}}                    & \textbf{CPU33} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|0c|}{Dimensiones}                      & A              \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|0c|}{Consumo}                          & B              \\ \hline
        \multirow{4.25}{2cm}{Ambiente de operación} & Temperatura & C              \\ \cline{2-3}
                                               & Ruido          & D              \\ \cline{2-3}
                                               & Vibración      & E              \\ \cline{2-3}
                                               & Schock         & F              \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lc}
        \toprule
        Item                  & CPU33 \\ 
        \midrule
        Dimensiones           & A     \\ 
        Consumo               & B     \\ 
        Ambiente de operación         \\
        \quad Temperatura     & C     \\ 
        \quad Ruido           & D     \\ 
        \quad Vibración       & E     \\ 
        \quad Schock          & F     \\
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still learning to use Latex and the fact that you took the time to send me several examples is great. I appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. The key `hvlines` draws all the rules excepted in the blocks (created by `\Block`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-bottom-limit=3pt,cell-space-top-limit=3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lcc}[hvlines]
\Block{1-2}{\textbf{Item}}           &             & \textbf{CPU33} \\ 
\Block{1-2}{Dimensiones}             &             & A              \\ 
\Block{1-2}{Consumo}                 &             & B              \\ 
\Block{4-1}{Ambiente\\ de operación} & Temperatura & C \\ 
                                     & Ruido       & D \\ 
                                     & Vibración   & E \\ 
                                     & Schock      & F \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]