# can anyone help me to do this LATEX table

Tags: tables, nicematrix

[image]

can anyone help me to do this table in latex and my text in t and f column is too much

Comment: it seems to be a usual table with `\multirow`. A google search will bring you to tutorials.

Comment: See also: [How can I draw a horizontal line spanning only some of the table cells?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8549/134144) The example code in the answer to this question can serve as a starting point for your table.

Answer (score 6):

As it is only a prototype, I know two ways to do what you ask, with minimal effort.

(1) Using excel to build a prototype of the table and export it to LaTeX using the add-on  Excel2LaTeX from:

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex?lang=en

[image: exc]

My only typing was changing the line `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}` to expand the columns and adding two packages.

[image: out1]

(2) The second example is using the package `nicematrix`.

The code is much cleaner because it provides the command `\Block` to define `multirow` and `multicolumn` cells (4 cells)
and also provides directives as `hvlines` to draw all lines, while respecting the blocks, and commands to expands all the cell vertically.

My only typing was search and delete all the `\cline`s and `\bigstrut`s plus changing the `\multirow`s for `\Block`

The package manual shows many examples to learn and test.

[image: nice]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{bigstrut} % for the first table
\usepackage{multirow}% for the first table

\usepackage{nicematrix} % the second table only needs the package

\begin{document}
    
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % expand & center column    

\section{Output from  Excel2LaTeX}  
    
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'    
%\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|} % original output from from Excel2LaTeX   
\begin{tabular}{|L{0.1\textwidth}|L{0.18\textwidth}|L{0.18\textwidth}|L{0.15\textwidth}|L{0.2\textwidth}|}  % set columns widths
    \hline
    F   & S                             & T     & F     & F  \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    1   & \multirow{10}[20]{*}{19}      & 23    & 40    & 58 \bigstrut\\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-5}2     &       & 24    & 41    & 59 \bigstrut\\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-5}3     &       & 25    & 42    & 60 \bigstrut\\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-5}4     &       & 26    & 43    & 61 \bigstrut\\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-5}5     &       & 27    & 44    & 62 \bigstrut\\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-5}6     &       & 28    & 45    & 63 \bigstrut\\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-5}7     &       & 29    & 46    & 64 \bigstrut\\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-5}8     &       & 30    & 47    & 65 \bigstrut\\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-5}9     &       & 31    & 48    & 66 \bigstrut\\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-5}10    &       & 32    & 49    & 67 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    11 & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{20}         & 33    & 50    & 68 \bigstrut\\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-5}12    &       & 34    & 51    & 69 \bigstrut\\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-5}13    &       & 35    & 52    & 70 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    14 & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{21}         & 36    & 53    & 71 \bigstrut\\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-5}15    &       & 37    & 54    & 72 \bigstrut\\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-5}16    &       & 38    & 55    & 73 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    17 & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{22}         & 39    & 56    & 74 \bigstrut\\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-5}18    &       & 40    & 57    & 75 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}%

\newpage

\section{Package nicematrix}

\begin{NiceTabular}{L{0.1\textwidth}L{0.18\textwidth}L{0.18\textwidth}L{0.15\textwidth}L{0.2\textwidth}}[% set columns widths
    cell-space-top-limit = 5pt,cell-space-bottom-limit = 5pt,   % expands all cell  
    hvlines % draw all lines
    ]
F     & S               & T     & F     & F   \\
1     & \Block{10-1}{19}& 23    & 40    & 58  \\
2     &                 & 24    & 41    & 59  \\
3     &                 & 25    & 42    & 60  \\
4     &                 & 26    & 43    & 61  \\
5     &                 & 27    & 44    & 62  \\
6     &                 & 28    & 45    & 63  \\
7     &                 & 29    & 46    & 64  \\
8     &                 & 30    & 47    & 65  \\
9     &                 & 31    & 48    & 66  \\
10    &                 & 32    & 49    & 67  \\
11    & \Block{3-1}{20} & 33    & 50    & 68  \\
12    &                 & 34    & 51    & 69  \\
13    &                 & 35    & 52    & 70  \\
14    & \Block{3-1}{21} & 36    & 53    & 71  \\
15    &                 & 37    & 54    & 72  \\
16    &                 & 38    & 55    & 73  \\
17    & \Block{ 2-1}{22}& 39    & 56    & 74  \\
18    &                 & 40    & 57    & 75  \\
\end{NiceTabular}
    
\end{document}
```